# how can i use scrollToIndex in FlatList React native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

what i'm trying to do is that when i run onPress, i want to scroll down as much as value of y (which is 499)

but if i use my code it doesn't work anything

this is my code

```
    const TodoList = ({}) => {

      const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
      const flatListRef = useRef()

    
      return (
        <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
          style={{height}}
          keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}

          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TodoItem
            onPress={() => {
              const node = flatListRef.current;
              if (node) {
                node.scrollToIndex({x: 0, y: 499, animated: true, index:0});
              }
            }}
            />
          )}
        />
```

what code should i fix?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong method. You should be using `scrollToOffset`

```
if (node) {
    node.scrollToOffset({ offset: 499, animated: true });
}
```